# Where the product admin images processed in magento 2?

Tags: product-images, gallery-image, product-edit, magento2.4.5p1

In Magento 2, if you go to

**Products->Catalog->Edit->Images and Videos**
you can add images to the product. The uploader will upload a temp image immediately.When click on save image will save agains product.

I want to know where this temporary file added to the existing images and show(load). And how can i add an external image in a temp location to this image gallery set and how can i refresh the gallery section with the external processed image.

I am using an ajax call to process and move the processed image to temp location.